# Do something when device can't receive message from GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to let my server know if a device can't receive message anymore from GCM. So for example when the phone shuts down or when the `GCMBaseIntentService` is killed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCM will hold on to your information as specified in TTL. GCM is a broadcast service, meaning that you should not know if the device has received the message or not.

One thing you can do is keeping track of your push messages. When application launched it submit the last received message to check with server.

Even if the device is on and online, there is no guarantee that it will receive the message from GCM.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know it holds the messages. But I want it not being able to send those message in the first place if the device is off. I'm making a messaging app and only want to be able to chat when both devices are on. So I'm using a offline/online status.

Comment: You can make the device ping back to server when receiving push message from GCM. Then you have logic on server-side monitoring ping request. Just an idea.

Comment: Ok. I guess this is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can Do is Unregister your GCM service from server when you are logged out from the app. so that if server will send the push notification to the Device it will not received by the Device. and whenever you again logged in your app you have to register your Device again to the Server.

you cant Register & Unregister your GCM Service by following code:

Register:

```
 GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    if (regId.equals("")) {
      GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
    } else {
      Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
    } 
registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
```

Unregister:

Write in OnDestroy Method the Following code:

```
unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
        GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
```

Let me know if you have any query regarding this.would be very glad to help you out.

Comment: The onDestroy method is called when a message is received and handled. So that is way too often.